# FileInfo delete() method not deleting files

Tags: c#

I have this function to delete files older than X amount of months, but it doesn't seem to delete them when I run the code: any guesses to why? When I check folder they are still there.

```
    public static void deleteFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo ddi = new DirectoryInfo(destination_path);
            if (ddi.Exists)
            {
                logFile.WriteLine("Log Entry: {0}", String.Format("{0:f}", dt) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                foreach (var filename in ddi.EnumerateFiles())
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename.ToString());//(destination_path + "\\" + filename);
                    if (fi.CreationTime < dt.AddMonths(-1) )
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            fi.Delete();
                            logFile.WriteLine("{0} was deleted successfully.", destination_path + "\\" + filename);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            logFile.WriteLine("The deletion process failed: {0}", ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
                logFile.WriteLine(String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("-------", 25)));
                logFile.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
        {
            logFile.WriteLine("Log Entry: {0}", String.Format("{0:f}", dt) + System.Environment.NewLine);
            logFile.WriteLine("Could not delete files from specified directory:  {0}", ex.Message);
            logFile.WriteLine(String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("-------", 25)));
            logFile.WriteLine();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: have you checked your log file

Comment: Have you made sure that fi contains an actual file? does fi.Exists() return true? does the expression fi.CreationTime < dt.AddMonths(-1) return true at all? is an exception thrown ? and if so what is it?

Comment: yes log file says all were deleted successfully, don't know why.

Comment: Do you also create them somewhere? Maybe this deletes them but other code (re)reates them. Difficult to help.

Comment: no creation, only moveTo() that moves them to destination_path, I am not even accessing files, just moving and deleting

Comment: @peters: why do you move them if you want to delete them?

Comment: Please note that `If the file does not exist, this method does nothing` as documented in MSDN. Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: What does filename.tostring equate to?

Comment: its for my job, creating some app to have it move files then after later delete them

Comment: I have filename.ToString() to convert var filename to string, it doesn't like it when I leave it filename only => ...= new FileInfo(filename)

Comment: You need to confirm the file path of the file to be deleted is correct.

Comment: I meant what is the value returned by filename.tostring() ?

Comment: returns the name of file in a {} so like : {thenameofthefile.txt} < just like that with real file name

Comment: Are you suggesting that it doesn't know where those file are? which folder?

Comment: As far as I can see, you are trying to delete something like 'myfile.txt' and haven't given it the full path.
In this case, use  File class instead of FileInfo

Comment: Do I have FileInfo = new FileInfo in the right place?

Comment: I know what happened: I used copyTo() just for testing purposes rather than moveTo(), where copyTo created new date of the file to be 5/4 when I copied it, rather than kept its original creation date. So, if the file is created on 2/10 and copied it today 5/4. then creation date is 5/4, rather than use moveTo() which would have kept 2/10.... so, nothing was deleted because I am saying if creation date > which is 5/4 is less than month ago, which is false, but my code is correct though.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 4):

As "Alessandro D'Andria" points out the documentation says:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.delete(v=vs.110).aspx

"If the file does not exist, this method does nothing."

This makes you think that the file delete has worked and is masking the issue.

If you look at the line:

```
foreach (var filename in ddi.EnumerateFiles())
```

this is returning a `FileInfo` object which is basically a link to the file you want to delete.

But the next line, creates a new `FileInfo` object based on the filename.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename.ToString());
```

But the `filename.ToString()` is just returning the filename, there is no path information in here.

If you run through the debugger you will see that the `fi` object will have a pathname (fi.Directory) which is not your `destination_path`, but is in fact the path of your running executable.

Therefore, fi.Delete() does not actually find the file, so it does nothing (as per the documentation) but you still write a 'success' message to your log file and no exception is thrown, so you wrongly think that everything has worked.

So you actually want something more like this;

```
if (filename.CreationTime < dt.AddMonths(-1))
{
    try
    {
        if (!filename.Exists)
            throw new Exception("File does not exist");

        filename.Delete();
        WriteLine("{0} was deleted successfully.", destination_path + "\\" + filename);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteLine("The deletion process failed: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the full path:

```
string path = Path.Combine(destination_path,filename.ToString());
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like.... (Ive left out some of your logic but the principle is the same....)
You don't need to use fileinfo as far as I can see.

```
{
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(destination_path);

        foreach (string filename in files)
        {
            if (File.Exists(destination_path + "\\" + filename))
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(destination_path + "\\" + filename);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logFile.WriteLine("The deletion process failed: {0}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```